# AXIS Client from WSDL making operation return type void

Tags: web-services, soap, axis, soapheader

The code in my stub is setting these following properties:

```
    oper.setReturnType(org.apache.axis.encoding.XMLType.AXIS_VOID);
    oper.setStyle(org.apache.axis.constants.Style.WRAPPED);
    oper.setUse(org.apache.axis.constants.Use.LITERAL);
```

The response structure is like:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:JCardViewSoapResponse0 xsi:type="ns1:JCardViewSoapResponse0"></ns1:JCardViewSoapResponse0></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

When I make the webservice call, I get an exception:

org.xml.sax.SAXException: SimpleDeserializer encountered a child element, which is NOT expected, in something it was trying to deserialize.

Any ideas?

Comment: Waybe an Encoding issue, or the WebService expects a diffrent structure then what you are sending

Comment: The problem is that the axis client is being generated with return type VOID to my operation